# To use "ものです" to end a sentence

Tags: grammar

The original sentence is:
人間は一人では生きていけません。
and the requirement is to change the sentence with a "ものです" ending.

I did this: 
人間は一人では生きていけないものです.

Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right.

(The system requires an answer to contain at least thirty characters.  This is a filler text to meet this requirement.)

Comment: カッコ内がおちゃめなので+1.